# Add expand functionality to images

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images

When we add images to posts, they're often shrunk to fit the web page (reduction of the width and height). I suspect this is done automatically by the HTML.

However, some times, we need to see the bigger picture (literally).

I often edit posts such as [Virus hides files, shrinks total capacity](https://superuser.com/questions/936811/virus-hides-files-shrinks-total-capacity) and add the option to view the large image by simply adding the image as a link.

Can/should this feature be enabled as standard? To have a link (some how) which shows the full version when ever we add a graphic (or at least, where applicable)?

Comment: I did write a userscript you can install to enable this functionality for yourself: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242232/187228 (I might make it lightbox instead if I ever get the time and will...)

Comment: Hey there! We are looking into inserting a link to images when they are uploaded using our image uploader.

Comment: Also duplicated on MSU: [Images that are wider than 640px](http://meta.superuser.com/q/4610/150988).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @thomasorozco...  The system works!!

Comment: This is now live! From now on, the image uploader automatically wraps images in a link to themselves. [Balpha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) is to thank for this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now live! From now on, the image uploader automatically wraps images in a link to themselves, which looks like this:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: Success!]

---

[Balpha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) is to thank for this change.

Comment: Thank you for the update and thank you @Balpha

Answer (score 3):

Cannot agree more. This would be a major improvement. Let's see if this gets picked up by the development team.

Would it be more applicable to global [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) then to just [meta.superuser.com](https://meta.superuser.com/)?

Comment: I have. Then saw it was a dupe. See my comment on my post

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the image clickable:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

This has been brought up several times in the past. There should be extensive discussions about it on MSE.

Comment: Yes, but it should be done at the point of posting, not due to an edit. Any way, you are of course right, turns out it's on MSE... I added a comment, is it worth closing this post?